# Дробные пиксели

Tags: gwt, html, internet-explorer, css

Я всегда считал, что значения в px  могут быть только целыми числами. Но недавно, отлавливая ошибку в Internet Explorer 10 обнаружил в панели разработчика следующее:

[image]

Дробные значения в пикселях везде.

При этом в GWT метод `getClientWidth/Height()` возвращает только целые значения. Как сделать совместимость с IE10? У меня во многих местах нужно один абсолютно позиционированный элемент отображать ровно над другим, а в IE10 он "дергается" (смещение менее, чем на 1 px).

И еще такой вопрос: а остальные величины (offset, padding, margin, coordinates) могут быть дробными в px?

Comment: А где вы взяли IE 10? я тоже хочу :)

Comment: Поставьте Windows 8, там будет IE 10.

Comment: А... А откуда вы взяли Windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дробное значение быть может, но это, скорее "неумность" разработчиков, или же "неумность" браузера при высчитывании ширины/высоты определенного DOM-элемента, установленного в дробное значение в процентах, например:

```
<div style="width:23.345%">
```

Браузер в таком случае производит простейшие математические действия для преобразования процентного соотношения в пиксельное без последующего преобразования результата в целое число(из дробного).

---

А вообще, дробное значения пикселя - это, конечно же, абсурд. Нельзя "закрасить" половину пикселя или же его треть. Должно быть понятно, что 123.86px == 124px

Comment: Понятно, что я не задаю руками дробные значения. Но ведь остальные браузеры игнорируют дробную часть. Как теперь с GWT  работать?

Comment: Да так и работайте! В данном случае можно просто не обращать внимания на дробную часть числа.

Comment: Все GWT-обертки возвращают только целые числа, а мне нужно вычислять точные значения. Как лучше это обойти? В IE10 моё приложение всё понемногу разъезжается в динамике.

Comment: Кажется на Хабре недавно читал про дробные пиксели. Смысл состоял в том, что пиксель браузера не всегда = пикселю вашего экрана. И сие хотели унифицировать чтобы сайты смотрелись одинаково на всех типах экранов. Надеюсь, что я ничего не путаю...

Comment: @Dexter вообще то "css пиксель" состоит не из одного реального пикселя и его размер зависит от масштаба/браузера и число css пикселей может быть не целым! [Вот статья...](http://www.beskrovnyy.com/verstka/skaz-o-dvux-vyuportax-chast-vtoraya/ "Сказ о двух вьюпортах")

Answer (score 3):

[[@Trash](/users/1406/trash)](/users/1406/trash) я преобразовал коммент к [[@Dexter](/users/7771/dexter)](/users/7771/dexter) в ответ т.к. считаю что он вполне имеет право быть ответом.
Вообще то "css пиксель" состоит не из одного реального пикселя и его размер зависит от масштаба/браузера и число css пикселей может быть не целым! [Вот статья](http://www.beskrovnyy.com/verstka/skaz-o-dvux-vyuportax-chast-pervaya/)

Answer (score 0):

Браузеры просто округляют дробное число пикселей до целого. Например 11.3 или 11.4рх браузер округлит до 11рх, а 11.5 или 11.6 браузер округлит до 12рх.